# speed up vector multiplication

Tags: r, performance, vector, max, multiplication

I would like to speed up the below R function. 
For each column in matrix 'A', find the index (not itself) for which its product with another element of the vector and the respective element in symmetric correlation matrix R is maximised.

Currently, there is some redundancy in calculating the outer product as it unnecessarily generates the full matrix. Also, the loop (i.e. 'apply') should ideally be vectorised.

Example data below.

```
    set.seed(123)
    A <- matrix(rexp(30000, rate=.1), nrow=3000, ncol=2000)/100
    R <- matrix( runif(10000), 3000 , 3000 )
    diag(R) <- 1
    R[upper.tri(R)] <- R[lower.tri(R)]

    function_which_is_too_slow <- function(index){
        aar <- outer(A[,index], A[,index]) * R
        diag(aar) <- 0
        return(max.col(aar, 'first'))
    }

    out <- apply(matrix(1:dim(A)[2]), 1, function_which_is_too_slow)
```

Comment: I know It does not play a role here, but for good practise, please use `set.seed` when using such functions as `runif`, etc...

Comment: Thanks, now reproducible.

Comment: The `apply` is unlikely to be the major issue with only 2000 columns. I'm not sure that you could do much better with base R. Your problem description seems to suggest that you will need to look at a minimum of 2000*3000*2999/2 = 9 billion products. You currently are looking at 2000*3000^2 products, which is greater by a factor of 2, but you are doing so with optimized functions like `outer` and `max.col`. If time is an issue, this seems like a natural use case for `rcpp`

Answer (score 2):

Here your code as base line with a smaller problem size:

```
set.seed(123)
A <- matrix(rexp(30000, rate=.1), nrow=3000, ncol=40)/100
R <- matrix( runif(10000), 3000 , 3000 )
diag(R) <- 1
R[upper.tri(R)] <- R[lower.tri(R)]

function_which_is_too_slow <- function(index){
  aar <- outer(A[,index], A[,index]) * R
  diag(aar) <- 0
  return(max.col(aar, 'first'))
}

system.time(apply(matrix(1:dim(A)[2]), 1, function_which_is_too_slow))
#>        User      System verstrichen 
#>      12.001      11.388      10.348
```

Setting the diagonal to zero every time is unnecessary, if we use a copy of the correlation matrix with the diagonal set to zero. Using `lapply` instead of `apply` just looks nicer:

```
Rp <- R
diag(Rp) <- 0

faster_function <- function(index){
  aar <- outer(A[,index], A[,index]) * Rp
  return(max.col(aar, 'first'))
}
system.time(lapply(1:ncol(A), faster_function))
#>        User      System verstrichen 
#>      11.156      10.306       8.334
```

We can also use RcppArmadillo to do the same computations in C++

```
Rcpp::cppFunction(code = "
arma::uvec arma_function(const arma::mat &A, const arma::mat &Rp, int index) {
  arma::mat aar = A.col(index-1) * A.col(index-1).t() % Rp;
  return index_max(aar, 1) + 1;
} 
", depends ="RcppArmadillo")
system.time(lapply(1:ncol(A), arma_function, A = A, Rp = Rp))
#>        User      System verstrichen 
#>       7.382      10.578       4.874
```

And we can parallelize the computations, though RcppArmadillo already uses OpenMP if available:

```
system.time(parallel::mclapply(1:ncol(A), arma_function, A = A, Rp = Rp))
#>        User      System verstrichen 
#>       0.008       0.010       3.903
```

Overall, about 3 times faster, which isn't a lot.